# How can I set different functions according to items selected on Listview?

Tags: java, android, listview

what I want to do looks easy but I can not handle with that.

I have a google spreadsheet that I am using for recording reservations of a hotel.

In the code there is checkIn() method and that method needs to perceive/understand the item=person clicked wants to check in at the hotel.

For example on the listview when I clicked the  3rd item/person, that click receives data from googlescript spesific for the 3rd row on googlesheet.
In that way 3rd row will be cut both on app and on google spread sheet and 
paste into another sheet.

I hope I could describe what I wanted to do.

Thanks in advance
Happy codding;

```
@Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:

                        break;

                    case 1:




                        break;
                }
                DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        switch (which){


                            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:

                                //Yes button clicked

                                checkIn();
                                break;


                            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                                //No button clicked
                                break;
                        }
                    }

                    private void checkIn() {
                        //StringRequest strq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST"")


                    }
                };

                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Reservations.this);
```

[Here what my listview looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJxC6.png)

Comment: In short, are you trying to set clickListener on the item of listview?

Comment: clicklistener is working perfectly. I am trying to figure out what code I can use so I can check in persons on lstview. You see there is a photo of my reservation lst in my name .That reservation list is from my google sheet. And there is code I post includes case and break for first 2 items/reservations. when I click first item I want to delete the first person or when I click the 5th item I want it to disappear.

Comment: or basically there are rows on googlesheet and I want to control those rows by clicking items on my listview on android studio, for example when I click first item on listview I want to do something about first row on my google sheet.